# Moving directories into subdirectories based on first character

Tags: directory, mv

I would like to move directories into another location and into subdirectories by first letter.
For example:
./alpha would move to /otherdir/a/
./beta would move to /otherdir/b/
All the subdirectories are created and it's a fixed set, so I don't need to worry about checking or creating those.
I was hoping to use the output from
`find . -type d -name "[a-z*]"`
, and when I run
`find . -type d -name "[a-z*]" | xargs mv -t /dest/`,
all the directories get moved, but of course not into subdirectories. I can't figure out if it's possible to use a second argument for the `/dest/first character here/` component, passing the first character of each directory name.
Is there a way to do this, or a different way to a) generate the directory list and b) pass the directory names and first characters to a move command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pick up the first letter of the directory.  It is easy to do that by running the output of `find` through a loop.  For example,

```
for i in $(find . -type d -name "[a-z]*")
do
    echo ${i:2:1}
done
```

This command gives you the first letter of each directory, ignoring the leading `./`.  To move it into a destination, you will have to put the directory elsewhere (above the current directory) to avoid recursive moves.  Let us say that your destination directories are in `../dest/a`, `../dest/b`, and so on.  You can replace the `echo` command with `mv` and the above loop can become

```
destination="../dest"
for i in $(find . -type d -name "[a-z]*")
do
    mv ${i} ${destination}/${i:2:1}
done
```

You'll have to adjust for destination.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for using `find` (unless the number of directories is huge).

```
dest_root='/otherdir'
for dir in [a-z]*; do
    [ -d "${dir}" ] && mv "${dir}" "${dest_root}/${dir:0:1}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you - makes sense. I'm assuming this would improve execution efficiency?

Comment: This will not just move directories but all the files.  I have edited the solution to move just the directories.